# How do I refer to a line of code from a C file?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I have a source code listing in my appendix. I have added it like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C]{Appendix/tcas/tcas.c}
```

I want to refer a line, e.g., line 72, from this file. How do I do this ?

Can I refer to this line from a different section ?

Comment: Add the `mathescape` option, and then insert `$\label{myline72}$` in your `tcas.c` at the appropriate location. Now you can reference it using `\ref{myline72}` in your document, if you add line numbers (of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `escapeinside` to add a `label` to a line which can then be referenced using `\ref` (or even `\cref` if you load the `cleveref` package), as described in the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) documentation- here's a little example

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}                                % nice verbatim environments
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,language={[LaTeX]TeX},   
    numbers=left,
}%
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}]
Hence determine how many zeros the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$
has on the interval $[0,9)$.(*@\label{line:interval1}@*)
\begin{shortsolution}
    The function $h$ has $10$ zeros on the interval $[0,9)$.(*@\label{line:interval2}@*)
\end{shortsolution}
\end{lstlisting}
Reference: \ref{line:interval1},\ref{line:interval2}

\end{document}
```